# how to insert rows from table to table using output

Tags: sql, sql-server

i got two tables..i want to copy the same sets of data from the table to itself but in table2 i want to copy the id in table1 to table2 id2.

```
Table1
      id      group       account 
   ------------------------------
      101     massive     balls
      201     nip         ripper
      301     holy        magnum

Table 2
      id    title      amount    id2
-------------------------------------
      1     expense     100.00   101
      2     local        50.00   201
      3     depart       25.00   301
```

here's what i already did but can't get the values of b.title and b.amount

```
INSERT INTO Table1

OUTPUT inserted.Id, B.title, B.amount 
INTO Table2(id2, title, amount) 

SELECT A.*,
         B.title,
           B.amount,
            B.id2    
FROM Table1 AS A

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT  title,
          amount,
           id2
 FROM Table2) AS B
 ON A.id = B.id2
```

the data in the table after inserting should be like this. same sets of data from table 1 and 2 but only copied the id of table1 to table2 id2

```
Table1
      id      group       account 
   ------------------------------
      101     massive     balls  
      201     nip         ripper  
      301     holy        magnum 
      302     massive     balls
      303     nip         ripper
      304     holy        magnum

Table 2
      id    title      amount    id2
-------------------------------------
      1     expense     100.00   101
      2     local        50.00   201
      3     depart       25.00   301
      4     expense     100.00   302
      5     local        50.00   303
      6     depart       25.00   304
```

Comment: Where do you get data for the Table 2 ?

Comment: table 2 have its own data..and table1.id and table2.id2 its their indentifier..

Comment: can you edit question and show me what you want to achieve it's really hard to get your question

Comment: @YoyieGuangco - do you wanna copy those data once? or need to do it every time? Also do you have existing data in Table1?

Comment: @Spider -  i want to copy it occasionally..and yes i have an existing data in table1..

Comment: You must use `cursor` and select data from joined tables. Then for every row you insert into `table1` if id was hanged and inesert into `table2` with new generated id for new row in `table1`.

Comment: @YoyieGuangco Hm... I just tried this in a dev environment and as far as I can tell, it should be sufficient to use `OUTPUT inserted.Id, inserted.title, inserted.amount` since b.title and b.amount are the ones you are inserting anyways...